# Axapta: How does temporally or inMemory tables works, multiple users once a time

Tags: axapta, temporal

Could you help to understand this approach:

I have to do a query that make some operations, i do not want to use containers, since i read that temporal tables are faster, at least for my case, but i dont get how it works:

The Web Service that i will use to make inserts in temporally table, will be consumed by some people in the same time, each values for each users will be diferents, because thats the reason why i want to do this.... but i dont understand how the temporal table, will manage data for each user; Because it will be only a table, so, if an user perform the WS, the table will contain some rows, but then another user could perform in the same time the WS, that should fill the table with another values, how is works?

Temporal tables are saved for each users or how it works, for my case?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both temp tables are based on scope. When variable/buffer goes out of scope tables are dropped. So each user or WS call uses its own table.

You can find specs here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg845661.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb314749.aspx

Comment: i apreciate your answer, finally i found another solution, but i will consider it for future cases, thanks